# C# public assemblies directory on linux

Tags: c#, dll

I'm having problems understanding the way that common C# libraries are stored and used. Specifically on Linux. Where are the public assemblies that are included with Mono? To include my own commonly used libraries, where would I store these to easily use them as with namespaces? I can find information about how they are made and their history, but not much about how they are used. I'm using Debian 9.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/assemblies-and-the-gac/

Comment: Do you mean you want to know, how to reference other projects/assemblies?

Comment: @Nikolaus No, I'm looking for the location of my Global Assembly Cache as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx

Comment: Installing things to the GAC (other than the framework itself) is a bad practice on Windows. There is no reason it would be any different on Linux. Just copy the relevant assemblies alongside the main executable.